# Laravel Forge kills the deploy script

Tags: laravel, gulp, forge

The Forge server has been linked to a GitLab repository. So every time I push my new commits to my master branch Gitlab triggers Forge's Deployment url.

The problem seems like my deploy script are taking too long time to execute, and this results in Forge are killing the script. Can I somehow avoid the killing of the deploy script?

My deploy script:

```
cd /home/forge/x.dk
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
npm install
npm install gulp
gulp --production
php artisan migrate --force
```

Deployment log:

```
From gitlab.com:x/x
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
gulp@3.9.0 node_modules/gulp
├── interpret@0.6.6
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.1
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── tildify@1.1.2 (os-homedir@1.0.1)
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── v8flags@2.0.10 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── liftoff@2.2.0 (extend@2.0.1, rechoir@0.6.2, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.1.6, findup-sync@0.3.0)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, defaults@1.0.3, mkdirp@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
└── gulp-util@3.0.6 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, beeper@1.1.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, vinyl@0.5.3, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@2.0.0, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.11)
[17:43:36] Using gulpfile ~/x.dk/gulpfile.js
[17:43:36] Starting 'default'...
[17:43:36] Starting 'less'...

Fetching Less Source Files...
   - resources/assets/less/style.less


Saving To...
   - public/css/style.css

[17:43:37] Finished 'default' after 1.02 s
[17:43:41] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Less Compiled!
[17:43:41] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
Message:
    not found: notify-send
[17:43:41] Finished 'less' after 5.15 s
[17:43:41] Starting 'less'...

Fetching Less Source Files...
   - resources/assets/less/admin-style.less


Saving To...
   - public/css/admin-style.css

[17:43:45] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Less Compiled!
[17:43:45] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
Message:
    notify-send must be installed on the system.
[17:43:45] Finished 'less' after 4.18 s
[17:43:45] Starting 'scripts'...

Fetching Scripts Source Files...
   - bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
   - bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/all.js

/home/forge/.forge/provision-1234567.sh: line 8: 21661 Killed                  gulp --production
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing this NPM stuff in the deploy script:

```
npm install
npm install gulp
```

Probably what you need is to install Gulp via SSH and then just let the deploy script runs `gulp --production` on each push.

To access your server via SSH follow this Laracast: https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge/episodes/4. It explains how to connect to the database but it's basically the same.

When you have SSH access, install Gulp with:

```
sudo apt-get update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late. The script is still timing out with your improvements. Not sure what todo from here.

Comment: @MichaelSørensen he would like you to install it once via SSH, and then edit your deply script to simply run gulp --production (instead of installing npm every time)